# Facebook PHP SDK Curl over proxy

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Im trying to setup php sdk. SDK is using Curl to make request. But i have to do this by proxy.

My OPTS:

```
  public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-2.0',
    CURLOPT_PROXYPORT      => '8080',
    CURLOPT_PROXY          => 'proxy',

  );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
print "<pre>"; print_r($opts);    print "</pre>";
```

this is printing:

```
Array
(
    [78] => 10
    [19913] => 1
    [13] => 60
    [10018] => facebook-php-2.0
    [59] => 8080
    [10004] => proxy
    [10015] => method=GET&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    [10002] => https://graph.facebook.com/naitik
    [10023] => Array
        (
            [0] => Expect:
        )

)
```

and print print_r(curl_error($ch)); returning:

```
Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT
```

What opptions should be used, to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

In case it is a problem with CURLE_SSL_CACERT, this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

added to

```
if (curl_errno($ch) == 60) {
.
.
```

should solve the problem.